# How to get the error code from BluetoothError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pybluez

I have this code for reading from a bluetooth socket:

```
socket.settimeout(timeout)
try:
  data = socket.recv(1024)
except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as e:
  if e.code == 11:
    self.connect()
```

obviously, I want to make a difference between a 'normal' timeout and some other problems (for example the bluetooth device switching off). The code above does not work because there is no `code` in the `BluetoothError` object.

In the exception, I do see a code though:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 36, in scan
    data = socket.recv(1024)
  File "<string>", line 5, in recv
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (11, 'Resource temporarily unavailable')
```

How can I get that code? I tried looking for reference documentation online, but couldn't find anything.

From the code, I can see it is in fact an `IOError`, and there doesn't seem to be a way to get the `errno`, is that correct?

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/tree/master/bluetooth

Comment: @Matt.St yes. Well, apparently it is an `IOError`. The question still stands, but I can search again now.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation recently and this is the approach I used.

```
except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as btErr:
        errCode = eval(btError[0])[0]
        if errCode == 11:
            self.connect()
```

According to the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EnvironmentError) errno can be None but args will give you the verbatim constructor arguments as a tuple.

> https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EnvironmentError

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I'm not saying it's a good solution :
(11, 'Resource temporarily unavailable') is a string, for example you get the "code" by adding 2, 3 or more characters.
Try this :

```
try:
    data = socket.recv(1024)
except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as ex:
    print( ord(ex.args[0][1]) + ord(ex.args[0][2]) )
```

Then you can replace by :

```
except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as ex:
    if( ord(ex.args[0][1]) + ord(ex.args[0][2]) == 98 ): #98 for error code 11 with 2 characters
```